# cv::imread() in OpenCV not reading my .png

Tags: c++, opencv, directory, imread

I am really new to OpenCV and I was wondering why my debug string for empty matrix is running when I check if I have a png in my directory. I can confirm that I do indeed have an image by given name in the specified directory.

relevant code:

```
    cv::Mat imgTrainingNumbers;
    imgTrainingNumbers = cv::imread("C:/Users/.../source/repos/AutoTrader/training_chars2.png");
    if (imgTrainingNumbers.empty()) {                               // if unable to open image
        std::cout << "error: image not read from file\n\n";         // show error message on command line
        return(0);                                                  // and exit program
    }
```

directory:
[image]

[image]

the program does run up until it tries to open an image. I am confused, why does it do this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the image you are using is of corrupted data. The imread() function will not return anything to your imgTrainingNumbers matrix if you...
`a. have not specified the path correctly`
`b. the image is not in a proper format/is corrupted`
`c. some linking issue`

Replace the image with something else to test the theory.

Comment: Ok. I will try this

Comment: The issue seems to be the image!